# Sitecore Federated Authentication Administrator Group

Tags: federated-authentication, azure-ad

Using `Sitecore 9 update 1` is there a way to mark `Azure AD` group as Sitecore administrator without creating new Administrator group in Sitecore?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have configured federated authentication properly. You can do this by mapping claims. 
This is an excerpt an example from @Bas Lijten 's blog.

> As the Administrator role isn’t a real role, but more a Sitecore user
>   property, this “role” needs to be set in a different way. The
>   Propertyinitializer can be used to achieve this. First, it reads a
>   claim (and its value) and if that claim has the defined value, the
>   property will be set:

```
<propertyInitializer type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.PropertyInitializer, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
<maps hint="list">
  <!--The mapping sets the Email property of the user profile from emailaddress claim-->
  <map name="email claim" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultClaimToPropertyMapper, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
    <data hint="raw:AddData">
      <!--claim name-->
      <source name="idp" value="Auth0" />
      <!--property name-->
      <target name="IsAdministrator" value="true" />
    </data>
  </map>
</maps>
```

Source: http://blog.baslijten.com/enable-federated-authentication-and-configure-auth0-as-an-identity-provider-in-sitecore-9-0/